# Find file and replace it with new file

Tags: php

I need to find all occurrences of a specific file and replace it with a new file. The file I'm replacing may be in random directories. I'm sure the below is NOT correct, but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

find . -type f -name thisfile.php; do `cp -Rf /path/to/file.php file.php`; done

NOTE: When I search for this solution I only find how to replace a line inside a file, this is NOT what I need, I need to replace the entire file with a new updated file.

Also, I've notice commands similar to this uses the grave accent, shouldn't it be a single quote?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name thisfile.php | while IFS= read f
do
  cp /path/to/file $f
done
```

You find all occurences of `thisfile.php` and read them in the `while` loop using `read`. Each iteration of the loop `f` contains the name of the next file to be overwritten.

`IFS` is used here to handle correctly files with leading spaces in their names.

Comment: I tried that and it's not working. Do I need to place a semicolon somewhere, or replace the $f with anything?

Comment: Using the code as is with correct path and filename I just get the > arrow prompt, and noway of getting back to root# prompt.

Comment: You can get back to tha main prompt pressing ctrl-c. The `>` prompt means that you've written something wrong, probably `done`. That prompt means that the sheel waits for the end of the construction that was started before.